# Convert INT (representing a UNIX-timestamp) into DBTIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I would like to do a dataflow-transformation. My source DB contains a INT-column with a UNIX-timestamp (I know this is crappy, it is a really old system, bla bla bla... ;) ). I would like to transform this INT-TIMESTAMP-thingy into something I can use for a Date-Dimension, preferably a DBTIMESTAMP.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL:

```
select DATEADD(s,unixtimestamp,'1970-01-01') as sqldatetimestamp 
from mytable
```

In an SSIS expression:

```
DATEADD( "S", [unixtimestamp] , (DT_DATE) "1970-01-01" )
```

Of course this is assuming that the unixtimestamp you have is truly that, which is defined as the number of seconds since 1-1-1970.